# Возможно ли через <use> использовать такой <svg>

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg, svg-спрайт

Все `<svg>` проходили с `id,symbol,path,defs` А тут я даже не знаю что с ним делать...Подскажите можно ли такой  закидывать в спрайт и потом использовать?

```
`<svg aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; width: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden;" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
```

Comment: Я его вытащил с макета...Мне нужно вставить значок "закрыть" в спрайт и потом использовать через use...

Comment: у меня есть спрайт... спрашиваю потому что с подобным кодом (а точнее его отсутствием) ничего нет...Найду другой - похожий...

Comment: здесь, на сайте есть раздел [svg-спрайт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svg-%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82) почитайте ответы-вопросы, может что-нибудь подберете для своего варианта

Comment: А почему такой svg нельзя закинуть в спрайт?

Comment: @Grundy закинуть можно, но бесполезно. Шапка SVG есть, а тела, фигур svg нет

Answer (score 1):

> Подскажите можно ли такой  закидывать в спрайт и потом
> использовать?

закинуть можно, но бесполезно. Шапка SVG есть, а тела, фигур svg нет

---

Ниже пример спрайта с тремя иконками. По наведению меняется дефолтный цвет на красный.
При подготовке иконок к включению в спрайт, обязательно удалите fill: stroke; и другие внутренние стили иконок. Так как у них приоритет выше, чем у внешнего CSS.

```css
use path{
fill:inherit;
stroke:inherit;
}

use:hover {
fill:red;
pointer-events:all;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg>
    <symbol class="icon" id="icon-1" viewBox="0 0 32 32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
        <g><path d="M16,2A14,14,0,1,0,30,16,14,14,0,0,0,16,2Zm0,26A12,12,0,1,1,28,16,12,12,0,0,1,16,28Z"/><path d="M17,7H15v8.52a2,2,0,0,0,.75,1.56l4.63,3.7,1.24-1.56L17,15.52Z"/></g>
    </symbol>
    <symbol class="icon" id="icon-2" viewBox="0 0 32 32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <g><polygon points="28.71 4.71 27.29 3.29 16 14.59 4.71 3.29 3.29 4.71 14.59 16 3.29 27.29 4.71 28.71 16 17.41 27.29 28.71 28.71 27.29 17.41 16 28.71 4.71"/></g>
    </symbol>
    <symbol class="icon" id="icon-3" viewBox="0 0 32 32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <g><path d="M16,2,3,6.28V12C3,26.61,15.63,29.94,15.76,30L16,30l.24-.06c.13,0,12.76-3.36,12.76-18V6.28ZM27,12c0,12.1-9.31,15.45-11,16C14.31,27.45,5,24.1,5,12V7.72L16,4.05,27,7.72Z"/><path d="M11.59,15l-1.42,1.41,2.29,2.29a2,2,0,0,0,1.42.59,2,2,0,0,0,1.41-.59l6.54-6.53-1.42-1.42-6.53,6.54Z"/></g>
    </symbol>
</svg>  
<svg height="64" width="64"><use xlink:href="#icon-1"></use></svg>
<svg height="64" width="64"><use xlink:href="#icon-2"></use></svg>
<svg height="64" width="64"><use xlink:href="#icon-3"></use></svg> 
</div>
<!-- Для вызова, если спрайт находится на сервере
<svg height="100" width="100"><use xlink:href="/icons.svg#icon-1"></use></svg>
<svg height="100" width="100"><use xlink:href="/icons.svg#icon-2"></use></svg>
<svg height="100" width="100"><use xlink:href="/icons.svg#icon-3"></use></svg>
-->
```